# Removing duplicate records in mysql

Tags: mysql

How To delete duplicate record in Table which all record in same

```
id|name|address
1 |   a|b
1 |   a|b
1 |   a|b
1 |   a|b
```

Only One Record left after deleting

Comment: id name address
1  a  b
1  a  b
1  a  b
1  a  b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a good reason to include an auto-incremented primary key in all tables.  Then you wouldn't have duplicates.

The simplest way is to use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table nodups as
    select distinct *
    from table t;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from nodups;
```

Comment: Without Using temp table in a single record remain

Comment: @Saurabh.jd . . . I cannot understand your comment.

Comment: I am asking Without using temporary table keep only single record

Comment: You can add a new column, assign it an increasing value, and then remove all rows but the minimum (or maximum).  The temporary table approach seems simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

AS you asking all records are same then keep only single record and delete others

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Table LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE (id, name, address)
```

This will remove all duplicate entries and will also prevent new duplicates to get inserted.
If you want to insert new duplicates later you can simply drop it again.

But like Gordon Linoff already said you should think about adding an auto-increment key...